# Node.js Puppeteer: How to receive XHR response of iframe (with JS web worker)

Tags: javascript, iframe, xmlhttprequest, puppeteer, web-worker

I have a page which communicates to a server every 10 seconds via XHR inside an iframe. I would like to monitor the responses (text/plain UTF-8).

Opposite to the DevTools Network list, it seems Puppeteer does not "detect"
XHR responses from inside iframes, with it's normal page procedure:

```
page.on('response', async (response) => {}
```

When the ID of the iframe is known, is there any way to receive the XHR responses of the iframe? (with a JS web worker doing the XHR requests)

Answer (score 0):

I have written this example which showcases that requests are indeed `captured` from inner frames of your `page`. You have to be careful, requests that fail won't actually trigger `page.on('response')` handler but will trigger `page.on('requestfailed')`.

Also make sure to call `await page.setRequestInterception(true)` before adding any request related handlers to your page!

Here is a working example: (it will only trigger `requestFailed` due to cross origin restrictions.)

```
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

function simulateRequest() {

    function doXmlHTTPRequest() {
        function reqListener() {
            console.log('xml done.')
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }

        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
        oReq.open("GET", "https://www.google.com");
        oReq.send();
    }


    setInterval(doXmlHTTPRequest, 2 * 1000)

}

// Easiest way to get an Iframe is by its name.
const findFrame = (frames, name) => {
    return frames.find(f => f.name() === name)
}

const main = async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    // have a page with only an iframe.
    const pageContent = '<iframe id="myFrame" name="frameName">'
    await page.setContent(pageContent)

    // important call!
    await page.setRequestInterception(true)

    page.on('response', async(res) => {
        console.log('Page response received..', )
    })

    page.on('requestfailed', () => {
        console.log('requestfailed recieved')
    })

    page.on('request', async(res) => {
        console.log('page request received..', )

        // make sure to continue request.
        res.continue()
    })

    // find the iframe!
    const targetFrame = findFrame(page.frames(), 'frameName')

    // set some test content..
    await targetFrame.setContent('<h1>hello</h1>')


    // add a script to iframe which simulates requests!
    await targetFrame.addScriptTag({

        // execute the function immediatly..
        content: `(${simulateRequest.toString()})()`
    })

}

main()
```

Comment: You are correct, I have tested your example: **regular** XHR responses of inner iframes are captured with Puppeteer. 
If the iframe contains a page with a JS web worker (doing the XHR requests) it will not be captured by Puppeteer.
Opening the Page with the JS webworker directly, it will capture the Responses.